# hg clone results in error 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host' randomly from one machine

Tags: mercurial, clone

I have seen other questions about mercurial resulting in 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host' errors, but not specifically this case.

When I clone or do a large pull from one particular machine (actually our CI box) I get this error. This machine has been cloning this project for months without any problem, but this has just started today.

If I clone to an early revision, sometimes it works, and sometimes I het the same message.

It seems to be fine from all other machines.

Disk space is not particularly low on the CI box, and no firewall settings have been changed.

Any clues on what else could be a cause or how to go about debuggin this?

Comment: What is a "CI box"? How do you share your repos? Via hg serve, Apache+hgweb, something else?

Comment: @Eiver CI box = continuous integration server and we share repos from a central hg repo, so hg serve I suppose

Comment: I am asking because you are facing a network issue rather than a Mercurial issue. A "central" hg repo is typically hosted on Apache or IIS web server, so I suggest you investigate your www server logs. Other than that, there are system logs. I don't know if the central repo is on Windows or Linux. In general Mercurial itself is not responsible for any communication, so this is not a Mercurial issue. Not directly at least.

Answer (score 0):

If your CI box is running `hgweb` (the WSGI container that is the production-grade version of `hg serve`) then it's probably running it in some WSGI container, be it apache, gunicorn or whatever.  If that container has a response timeout after which it cuts off the response, sometime 10 or 30 seconds, then perhaps you need to increase it.

Regardless as @Eiver suggests what you have isn't a mercurial problem but a web server problem and it one that the person administering the web server needs to solve for you.